# Windows\Installer folder cleanup. Clean msp & msi patches marked as superseded

Tags: windows-10

Has anyone tried this script ?

https://forums.mydigitallife.net/threads/presenting%E2%80%A6-startcomponentcleanup-for-msi-including-office.77708/

It cleaned up about 6Gb of files in my windows\installer directory most of them was old Office 2016 patches.

Is there a downside of cleaning up old and marked as superseded msp & msi patches in installer directory ?

Comment: Yes, the downside is whenever _something_ gets corrupted and Windows Installer prompts for a particular MSI you may not have it. On the other hand if you do regular backups you may never run into such situation.

Comment: You can also not uninstall any item you remove from there. It’s been a while, but I believe I prefer this tool for cleaning up MSIs that are no longer needed: https://www.homedev.com.au/free/patchcleaner

Comment: If there was any problem with that script it would have been evident in that thread from members. It appears they are doing patch removal properly and without any consequences

Comment: @0xC0000022L: that script removes only msp files, using the MS API, which has [extensive checks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/uninstallable-patches) for what patch is unistallable. `dism /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup` (intro'd in Win 10 IIRC) is probably similar enough. The only thing that's not very clear from MS docs, is what does "status = 2", i.e. superseded actually mean. A badly authored patch might set that but not actually be fully superseded, as far as I can tell.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/clean-up-the-winsxs-folder "Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016 automatically reduce the size of the WinSxS folder by using methods similar to the ones described in this topic, in addition to internal processes, such as uninstalling and deleting packages with components that have been replaced by other components with newer versions. "

Comment: @Fizz if you have authored your own MSIs, be it in WiX or in some other tool, you'll know that there are plenty of times when - for seemingly no good reason - Windows Installer requests some installation source. You are right, that MSPs are less of an issue, but there are edge cases when they may be required. And then the question is if you can supply it when it's needed or not.

Comment: The issue is that "superseded" doesn't seem to do much https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664040/wix-superseding-patch-doesnt-do-anything

Comment: @Fizz WinSxS (Windows side-by-side) is a whole different story, why are you mixing those topics?

Comment: Yeah, but SxS cleanup is not only thing Win 10 does; see above "in addition to internal processes, such as uninstalling and deleting packages with components that have been replaced by other components with newer versions." Admittedly that's not very clear what it means/does.

Comment: @Fizz the author of [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19664040/476371) doesn't give enough information actually. We'd need to know information such as product code and upgrade code as well as whether the versions are _actually_ changed in the DLL resources (because that's how Windows Installer works). So it's absolutely not clear from that Q&A that this "not working" is caused by Widnows Installer as opposed to the author and the way the MSP/MSI was authored.

Comment: But regarding MSPs and asking for source, if they are uninstalled, it can't possibly the case that Windows asks for a source for them later. But it's quite possible the app will break. Heath (from MSFT) gave a somewhat clearer [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39545511/3588161) on what superseded does... which is nothing basically.

Comment: @Fizz if they are indeed uninstalled, you're perfectly right! However, Microsoft pulled a tool that was touted to be usable for the purpose (part of MS Office IIRC), because it did _not_ reliably only clean up stuff that wasn't installed. Also installed has shades in MSI, e.g. "advertised" ... anyway, the gist of the story being that is MS can't get it right, knowing _everything_ about the innards of Windows Installer, why would you want to trust a third-party script to get it right?

Comment: Well at least for their Office suite MS is daring enough to provide a list of MSPs to install, which aren't all MSPs they've ever released for that suite, which means that at least for their well-authored MSPs supersedence does seem to work properly
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/msp-files-office-2016

Answer (score 0):

Well, I ran this as an experiment on an old office computer with Win7 and Office 2010. The major downside of this script is the runtime: slightly over two hours even though this (i3) PC had a SSD. The gain was about 9GB of disk space from all those intermediate Office patches removed... but the script created 20GB of logs in temp, so this isn't very practical if you're running out of space. (I made the script output to a log as well: it removed about 700 patches.)

I noticed no ill effects: there are no new updates offered if you check for updates after running the script, so it doesn't remove anything essential and Office still runs and can be serviced (add/remove components works).

---

Somewhat theoretical answer: if the MSPs are well designed, nothing should break just from running that script, unless you later uninstall patches (either manually or some automated process does it) in which case you'll find out if the patches were well designed.

As [Heath (MSFT) explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39545511/3588161), if you remove superseded patches, what can happen is that if the "top patch" is then manually removed too, you're left with a much older (and buggy) version of the app than you might expect. And my thinking is that in combo with the feature that some superseded packages may be non-uninstallable/"permanent" could break some apps; skip two paras for details how that could happen.  (`permanent` is the keyword [used in the `.mum` file](https://borncity.com/win/2016/10/21/windows-updates-fehlende-deinstallation-erzwingen/).)

But before we get to that scenario, let me clarify something (which is a good way to see what's going on): the superseded patches, while still present in the registry (that's how that script finds them) are not shown at all (at least on Win 7) in the installed updates, unless they are also not marked as non-uninstallable/. (I tested this myself, by modifying that script to not remove anything, but just list what it would do, and then checking the patches in the Control Panel.) But if you do uninstall a top patch, causing a superseded but uninstallable one to become unsperseded, it will pop back on that Control Panel list, when you refresh it. (The writers of some 3rd party wix toolsets [found this behavior pretty confusing](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/fixing-a-bug-superseded-patches-are-not-removed-by-bundle-td7586911.html).)

Also, removing superseded patches should not be confused with [`msizap g`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/msizap-exe) which removes orphaned patches that are present in dir but not referenced in the registry (at all). The latter is [necessary sometimes too](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/setup/how-to-safely-delete-orphaned-patches/#:%7E:text=After%20safely%20identifying%20orphaned%20patches,data%20files%20such%20as%20patches), when some apps "spam" patches that they don't even register at all (VS 2005 was apparently famous for this.)

But there is actually a way to break an app with badly designed patches by uninstalling the intermediate/superseded ones: say you have files A and B, initially both at version 1.0. Patch X puts file A at ver 1.1, which is ok with file B at 1.0. Then patch Y puts file B at ver 1.1, which also compatible with A at 1.1, but incompatible with A at 1.0. But somehow this patch Y is made non-uninstallable, which can actually happen in [a large number of ways](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/uninstallable-patches). After those, you have patch Z which puts file A and B at 1.2. Then someone runs the script which uninstalls patch X (superseded), but can't uninstall Y (superseded but non-uninstallable). And then they manually roll back patch Z, leaving exposed file A version 1.0 and B version 1.1 (from patch Y). And this breaks the app.

Admittedly, this kind of scenario probably does't happen with MSFT apps for which they give a list of most recent MSPs (patches) that are safe to install by themselves, i.e. without all ancestor MSPs being installed. MS does this [e.g. for Office 2016](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/msp-files-office-2016), but not for 2010 (although they even bothered to make a click-to-run version of 2010). And from my quick checks with the script, Silverlight bestows (a lot of) non-uninstallable (the script calls them "permanent") but superseded patches, so such things do exist even in the MS realm. Actually Office 2010 has a few too, e.g.:

```
Microsoft Office Proof (Chinese (Traditional)) 2010 : Security Update for Microsoft Office 2010 (KB2760781) 64-Bit Edition is a permanent patch, run this script with /f to uninstall it
```

And Adobe Acrobat Reader DC also behaves pretty much like Silverlight, with a lot of non-uninstallable & superseded patches.

---

Also of some note, a fairly old MS document from the Vista days [said](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/askcore/what-is-the-winsxs-directory-in-windows-2008-and-windows-vista-and-why-is-it-so-large) that removing superseded stuff from `%windir%\Installer` is a *prerequisite for safe removal from from SxS* (which is another source of bloat):

> The only way to safely reduce the size of the WinSxS folder is to reduce the set of possible actions that the system can take – the easiest way to do that is to remove the packages that installed the components in the first place. This can be done by **uninstalling superseded versions of packages that are on your system**. Service Pack 1 contains a binary called VSP1CLN.EXE, a tool that will make the Service Pack package permanent (not removable) on your system, and remove the RTM versions of all superseded components. This can only be done because by making the Service Pack permanent we can guarantee that we won’t ever need the RTM versions.

So removing superseded stuff from `%windir%\Installer` should also help with reducing the SxS size. Note that there are semi-automated ways that do the later (after some superseded patch really is uninstalled, using the API, not plain deletion, I suspect):

- in Win 7 SP1 a method was introduced circa 2013 with [kb2852386](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2852386/disk-cleanup-wizard-addon-lets-users-delete-outdated-windows-updates-o) which adds a new disk cleanup (app) plugin. But this won't uninstall any app-related MSPs from `%windir%\Installer` by itself, I've tested that. This plugin logs its deeds in `%SystemRoot%\Logs\CBS\DeepClean.log`. There you can see stuff like:

```
Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~7601.23642.1.0 superseded - uninstalled
2020-07-03 06:47:01, Info                  CBS
```

- In Win 10 [there's](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/clean-up-the-winsxs-folder) `dism /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup /ResetBase` which seems to turn every non-superseded patch into an uninstallable "service pack", according to its documentation. In fact the documentation of the latter suggests it might also do some superseded patch uninstallation too, but I haven't really tested what it does. MS claims:

> Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016 automatically reduce the size of the WinSxS folder by using methods similar to the ones described in this topic, in addition to **internal processes, such as uninstalling and deleting packages with components that have been replaced by other components with newer versions**. Previous versions of some components are kept on the system for a period of time, allowing you to rollback if necessary. After a period of time, these older components are automatically removed from the installation. [...]
>
> Using the /StartComponentCleanup parameter of Dism.exe on a running version of Windows 10 gives you similar results to running the StartComponentCleanup task in Task Scheduler, except previous versions of updated components will be immediately deleted (without a 30 day grace period) and you will not have a 1-hour timeout limitation. [...]
>
> **Using the /ResetBase switch with the /StartComponentCleanup parameter of DISM.exe on a running version of Windows 10 removes all superseded versions of every component in the component store.** [...] All existing service packs and updates cannot be uninstalled after this command is completed. This will not block the uninstallation of future service packs or updates.

Also of some interest, someone else on that same MDL forum [wrote a /ResetBase equivalent for Win 7](https://forums.mydigitallife.net/threads/giveaway-windows-7-component-store-cleanup-tool-rebase.73817/). I haven't tested it. The latter hack looks a lot more complicated than the simple script mentioned by the OP. It also "ships" with a full complement of `dismcore.dll` & etc. dlls from a (by now) old version of Win 7, so I'm skeptical it works well with the later servicing stacks.